# FTPS on Azure Worker role

Tags: sockets, azure, ssl, ftps

I need to deploy a Azure Worker Role with input endpoint on port 21 so that it can accepts incoming FTP connections.so that i should be able to connect to worker role through FTP Client like Filezilla and access the azure blob storage.

For secured communication between client and SErver(Azure worker role) i need to implement AUTH TLS/SSL command.

can we able to support FTP over SSL/TLS - aka FTPS (FTP secure) on Azure Worker role via socket programming(tcplistener and tcpclient).

Regards,
Vivek.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF you make sure that FTP server is running in the Windows Azure Worker Role, you sure can configure a TCP/IP endpoint in worker role set to use port 21 and then configure a SSL certificate set over this TCP/IP endpoint. Once endpoints are properly configured in the worker role along with SSL certificate bindings, and the application listening on those port is able respond to incoming connections, you can make secure FTP connection.

The bottom line is that you would need to configure it correctly they way you want and the infrastructure will not prohibit your doing so, just you would need to make it happen correctly.

Comment: Hi Avkash,Thanks for the response.I was able to have FTP configured(port 21) on azure worker role.Could you please point to a url or tutorial where i can find configuring SSL certificate over worker role.

Comment: Do i need to implement AUTH command to support TLS for ftp service on azure worker role???

Comment: Vivek,Great work. I haven't tried FTP configuration by my own so I may not give you correct answer if AUTH is needed. What you can do is capture the network packets and decipher the message flow and see if AUTH is needed and if you see it was, just implement it otherwise not. Good luck.